# VBA - Populate listbox in userform with data from table using value from cell in other sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file with three sheets. Sheet1 has a combobox (A1) and a cell (B1) that open an userform (that has a listbox) when is clicked (only when the combobox has a value). Sheet2 has a list of names of people (10 in total, from here the combobox get the list). Sheet3 has a table with 3 columns: Name, Place, Phone, in here the names are the same from sheet2, but because of the column Place and Phone, some values are repeated in name, ex:

1. John, House, 312323
2. John, Work, 123142

What i'm trying to do is to populate the listbox with the data from Sheet3 using the value from the combobox from Sheet1, ex: select Jonh in the combobox and click in the cell to open the userform, the opened userform shows the listbox with data of john (the same i use in first example).

Using `Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 1).Address).Value` i can get the value from the combobox in the same row of the cell that active the userform, but i don't know how to populate the listbox.

Edit: using this code i was able to do the trick

```
Dim LR As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim i As Long
    ListBoxEmails.Clear
    With Sheets("MaeProv") 'sheet3
        LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Range column A Sheet3
        For r = 2 To LR
            If .Cells(r, 1).Value = Range(Cells(Selection.Row, 1).Address).Value Then 
                ListBoxData.AddItem .Cells(r, 2).Value 'populate listbox with data from column B and C of the same row of data (using data validation in cell A1 of sheet1 with list of names in sheet2)
                ListBoxData.List(i, 1) = .Cells(r, 3).Value
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next r
    End With
```